# Is it "on the title" or "in the title"?

Tags: prepositions

For example:

What would be better

*"I misspelled a word in the title"*

Or

*"I misspelled a word on the title"*

I seem to have a bit of a hard time with these prepositions; in, on or at.

I have found images like this one but it isn't really helpful when it comes to things other than time or places. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of the proper location preposition depends on the object it is used with.
If the object is a surface, you should use 'on'.
For example: on the page, on the wall, on the ceiling, on the platform, etc. 
If the object is a volume, space, or something solid, you should use 'in'.
For example: in the car, in the room, in the rain, in the letter, etc. 
In your case 'the title' is used not as a surface. 
So the only preposition to use here is 'in': 
IN THE TITLE.

Comment: I think I got it! Can there be a sentence that I could use "on the title"?

Comment: @Sirena S. C. If you're referring to a hair on the title of a physical book, then you can say "there's a hair on the title".

Comment: A hair is NOT on the title, it is on the page or book cover where the title is written or printed.

Comment: @SirenaS.C. To say something on the title=can be understood as **about the title**. But the preposition is due to: say something on something. See? Would you like to say something**on that**??